# UV unwrap or geometry issue (cylindrical object)

Tags: modeling, uv, geometry, resolution

I have created a mason jar object, and I am primarily having issues unwrapping the lid part of the mesh:
[image]

When attempting to unwrap properly and avoid an overhead projection type mythology that requires placing the rings in a separate location in the UV space, I am not sure how to reconcile the result of the unwrap.

I want to avoid a lengthy manual process of manually moving around vertices in the UV space to achieve a good result.

[image]
Using the unwrap methodology above yields seams when brought into Substance Painter and having materials applied.

I am also trying to unwrap the entire object onto one UV image and even at 2k, the results seem fairly low resolution.  I have made sure transformations were applied to the object prior to unwrap, so the relative size of different parts of the UV shouldn't be the issue.
[image]

My goal is to have a fairly clean unwrap that allows for as few seams as possible and a maximize usage of the UV space in a 2k image.

Is there a better way to mark the seams?

Is my overall geometry unsound for efficient UV unwrapping and maximizing use of space?

Also, the interior faces may be important as I plan on applying alpha transparency to the materials applied to the lid and jar of the object.

I have attached the blend file if anybody was interested in taking a look and pointing me in the right direction.

[image]

I plan to use the model in the Unity environment.

Thanks!

Comment: When adding a .blend, don't provide just the url of the website, please provide the link given at the site. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lid probably only needs a single UV seam on its lower inside edge.

[image]

Then you can arrange the UV's something like in the screenshot below: 
[image]

Your jar was almost 2 meters tall. Unless you have a special reason not to I would suggest that you always model to real world dimensions. In this casxe scaling it down to size ( **s** **0.1**  giving a more realistic jar hight of 180mm) means you get 10 times the texel density on the finished model when using the same size texture.
(2K texture for such a model seems a bit excessive :) )

Also, you have way to many edge loops in the Wires. I would suggest removing as many as 4 out of 5 in the Low version.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks for the response.

Comment: What was your methodology for straightening the verticle edges of the jar in the UV?  Did you select each edge and scale to 0 or is there a faster method?  Thanks.

Comment: To straighten edges; For the first edge : Alt LMB to select edge, RMB to open the context menu popup and choose either the Align X or Align Y option. For the next edge : Alt LMB the the key board short cut to Repeat Last operation which is Shft R but I have my repeat last operation mapped to a single key (tilde key  ( ~ ) which I find quicker and easier to use.

Comment: Appreciate the help, thanks!